# DataBinding not working after Upgrade Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, android-databinding, android-studio-2.3

DataBinding worked very well in my project,  But after upgrade Android Studio 2.3 today . **Run 'app'** failed because following error :

```
Error:(15, 40) Error: package com.javan.myrecorder.databinding not exist.
import com.javan.myrecorder.databinding.FragmentEventsBinding;
:app:compileMockDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

I just upgrade android studio and didn't change anything. all plugin is latest! Now my question is, why occurs this error and how could I solve it? any help is welcome!

English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.

---

EDIT1

Like android project [googlesamples/android-architecture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

- `git checkout todo-databinding`
- and then run `./gradlew assembleDebug` to build, build failed because of following error:

[complete log of build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwMyA.png)

---

EDIT2 **I have fixed this problem by following [Data Binding broke after upgrade to Gradle 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570707/data-binding-broke-after-upgrade-to-gradle-2-3/42590471#42590471)**.

in `build.gradle(app)` add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

..balabala

dependencies {
    apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'
}
```

some file in my project:

`gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
#Mon Mar 06 10:59:04 CST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

@petrnohejl @George Mount @Sa-Zad Prasla, Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem with android.databinding.PropertyChangeRegistry. It gives me an error in the import statement and I cannot compile the project. When I revert back to Build Tools 2.2.3, it works. I think there is something wrong with data binding on 2.3.

Comment: Do you see any other error?

Comment: Also, do you have anything else different in your configuration, such as apt?

Comment: @GeorgeMount  hi I'll paste more error log later, thank you for your reply, thanks

Comment: @George Mount , I have added some error log ; I guess there is something wrong with gradle or data binding , because in branch todo-databind of poject [googlesamples/android-architecture](https : //github#com/googlesamples/android-architecture ) which belong to google also build failed like below .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`android-apt` and hence using `apt` has been deprecated since Android Studio 2.2.
Following the [android-apt migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration), instead add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' // use same gradle version!
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'
}
```

If you are using Kolin, instead use:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' // use same gradle version!
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'
}
```

Comment: It worked for me when in addition to this change , I also downgraded gradle version to 2.3.0

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }

Comment: @Tushar thanks, I've updated the answer to makes sure of that you're using the same gradle version

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes in a warning that is difficult to see amongst all of the errors:

Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.

If you remove apt, data binding works.

Comment: add `apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'` to build.gradle. and now every thing is ok, instant run works. be the version of data binding compiler which cause the error ?

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same issue.
I was using ButterKnife and Dagger!!

Solved as follow

1) Remove from app level gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: 'android-apt' 
 or apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

2) Remove from project level gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

3) And simply change "apt to annotationProcessor" as following dependencies:

```
 apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1',
 apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5"
```

To:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1',
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Data binding also broke for us following the update to Android Studio v2.3. The GoLang Bind plugin became unable to generate library `.aar` files

Our problem was resolved via a combination of GoMobile version "+eb90329 Mar 7 2017" update and GoBind plugin revert to version "0.2.6" (although the current version is "0.2.8")

Update GoMobile:

```
  $ go get -u -x golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile
  $ gomobile init -x
```

Revert GoBind plugin in build.gradle:

```
  plugins {
    id "org.golang.mobile.bind" version "0.2.6"
  }
```

This solution is working on systems with go version 1.7.1 and 1.8 as well as Android Studio versions 2.1.2, 2.2.3, and 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Two things
Revert back your gradel-wrapper.properties distributionUrl to "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip" 
Change the gradle version classpath to previous version "'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'"

P.S. Instant run will stop working on ADT with older gradle version.

Comment: Hi @Sa-Zad Prasla, Revert back my gradle version is work, but not the best solution, Thank you for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

I too recently downloaded the latest version of android studio 2.3.3, because I was getting the same error in version 2.2.3 i.e **Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:compiler:2.2.3** ,even in the latest version, I was getting the same error,I checked the project structure, In the **File>Project Structure>Project** , the Android Plugin version was still 2.2.3, I changed it to 2.3.3 and the build is successful and everything is working smoothly.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem by changing my version of gradle to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Since I am using Android Studio 3.0.1